# CosmosClient read() only returning object if ID and partition key value are specified

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-cosmosdb

I've set up a CosmosDB instance and put one test object into the container `products`. The partitioning key is set to `/price`.

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "A DB product",
    "price": 12,
    "_rid": "RsMLAID7jXIBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/RsMLAA==/colls/RsMLAID7jXI=/docs/RsMLAID7jXIBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"270011a1-0000-0200-0000-5e8c61ef0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1586258415
}
```

If I read all items of the container, I get back that particular item:

```
const client = new CosmosClient(process.env.CosmosDbConnectionString);
const database = client.database("maindb");
const container = database.container("products");
const items = await container.items.readAll().fetchAll()
```

This is what I see in the debugger:
[image]

If I try to get the same item by id, the element won't be found:

```
const item1 = await container.item("1234").read()
```

This yields:

[image]

The only way of making it work is to change the read code to:

```
const item1 = await container.item("1234", 12).read()
```

This means I have to specify the exact partition key value but what if I want to query *just* by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means I have to specify the exact partition key value but what if
>   I want to query just by ID?

That's correct. A combination of `PartitionKey` and `id` uniquely identifies a document. You could have two documents in different partitions with the same id.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced by this answer. `read()` method's partition parameter is *optional* (`?`). That wouldn't make sense if the partition key were required.

Comment: I think you would need to see this in context with `read` operation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/item?view=azure-node-latest#read-requestoptions-). So you define partition key either when creating an instance of item or performing the read operation on that item.

Comment: I have been trying to find a straight answer to "but then how do I get ALL the documents" to wipe a container? (i.e. what if you don't know anything about the values, you just want to delete?) and EVERY TIME the answer is : "you need the partition key". This is starting to be annoying. Can anyone make sense of CosmosDb please?

Answer (score 1):

@Krumelur

For a partitioned collection you will have to provide the partition key when reading an item by ID. For non-partitioned collection you don't have to provide the partition key.

If you want to retrieve an item by ID without a partition key, then you could use items.query. This will return all the items with the specified Id in the query. If the ID is unique you will get only one item. Bear in mind that this query will have to look at all partitions to find the item, as you are not providing the partition key.